# How can I color code a log file based on fail, warning and info messages?

Tags: logs, colors

How can I color code a log file based on fail, warning and info messages? So that if I see the log file in web browser, it gives me colorful log file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot differentiate syslog log level (if that is what you want) after the logs are written to the log file. But lnav: http://lnav.org/ supports auto-coloring for many log types.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if this is a one time operation or something permanent so the following may be overkill.

Tools like [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) and similar may do what you want and both probably do a lot more.